# What are the right rites to \write right now?

Tags: macros, write

(with apologies for the title)

I've just entered the murky waters of trying to get one LaTeX file to write out something useful as it goes along.  In brief, I want my lecture LaTeX file to be able to write out a file that, upon LaTeX'ing, will give me the corresponding lesson plan.  So at the start of the (main) document I want to write out the header, then as the document progresses, I want to write out bits to go in the plan, then at the end it needs to write out a footer.

What is confusing me is *when* writes happen.  The lecture file consists of lots and lots of lectures (it's a beamer file) and only one is produced upon LaTeX'ing, but one of the pieces of information that I want to write out is the lecture title and I keep getting the last lecture title.  I thought that maybe `\immediate` would be the answer, but that really does mean **immediate**.  What I want is to put the `\write` in a macro in such a way that when the macro is called, the write is immediate (in particular, I want to hook it in to the lecture title page).  So the question is: how do I do that?

I'm probably just missing something obvious, but whatever it is, I'm missing it!

(And for some reason, searching on google for 'latex write' doesn't help much.)

Comment: I heard the rites have something do do with waving a dead chicken above your computer... have you tried that? :P

Comment: The title is so Donald Knuth-y

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess I must not understand the question. What is wrong with:

```
\newcommand{\mywrite}[1]{\immediate\write\myoutputfile{#1}}
```

Although I like to be a bit more complete and handle the fact that not all input files may be read on each compilation (due to `\includeonly`) but you still want the complete lesson plan even if some parts live in the non-included files, also the user maybe want to switch off all file output via `\nofiles`, or only wants to stop automatically updating the lesson plan so they can do some hand editing (here remove the `\makemyrecords` line). I would also want to avoid putting spurious spaces in the document, so I would do it this way, modelled loosely after how `\makeindex` works in latex:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myrecords}%
          [2010/08/14 v0.01 my example record package (LSB)]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\def\myrec@outputfileextension{.mrc}
\newcommand*{\myrec@write}[1]{}

\def\myrec@verb{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning}

\newcommand*{\makemyrecords}{%
    \newwrite\myrec@outfile
    \immediate\openout\myrec@outfile=\jobname\myrec@outputfileextension
    \typeout{Writing my records to file \jobname\myrec@outputfileextension}%
    \let\makemyrecords\@empty
    \renewcommand*{\myrec@write}[1]{\immediate\write\myrec@outfile{##1}}%
}
\@onlypreamble\makemyrecords

\newcommand*{\myrecord}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \if@filesw
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myrecordentry{#1}}%
    \fi
    \@esphack
}

\newcommand*{\myliteral}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \if@filesw
        \def\@tempa{#1}
        \immediate\write\@auxout{%
            \string\myrecordentry{%
                \myrec@verb\@tempa}}%
    \fi
    \@esphack
}

\newcommand*{\mywritecurrenttitle}{
    \if@filesw
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myrecordentry{%
            \string\lessonplanitem{\currenttitle}}}%
    \fi
}

\newcommand*{\myrecordentry}[1]{}
\AtEndDocument{%
    \renewcommand*{\myrecordentry}[1]{%
        \def\@tempa{#1}%
        \myrec@write{\myrec@verb\@tempa}%
}}

\endinput
```

If I test this with what I imagine you have in mind (obviously you would want to wrap the \renewcommand{\currenttitle}\mywritecurrenttitle up with a command that generates the document sectioning, or put them in hooks provided by your document class).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{myrecords}
\makemyrecords
\begin{document}
\myliteral{
    \documentclass{lessonplan}
    \begin{document}}
\newcommand*{\currenttitle}{This is the title of lesson 1}
\mywritecurrenttitle
Lesson 1....

\renewcommand{\currenttitle}{This is the title of lesson 2}
\mywritecurrenttitle
Lesson 2.....

\myliteral{\end{document}}
\end{document}
```

Then, as expected, the lesson plan file looks like

```
\documentclass {lessonplan} \begin {document}
\lessonplanitem {This is the title of lesson 1}
\lessonplanitem {This is the title of lesson 2}
\end {document}
```

Comment: This is great!  Thanks.  With a little tweaking to take into account the details I _didn't_ tell you about, it's now a working solution.  (Basically, I can't use the aux file route because I want the lesson plan to be generated when `\nofiles` is in effect.  But it was simple to edit that out.)

Comment: A follow-up: I'm now using this "in the wild" and it's fantastic.  I now scatter my beamer presentation with the lesson plan stuff, plus a few things are added automatically, and my lesson plan gets written out into a separate file which I can TeX to get a very nice-looking plan.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use `\let` to save the current title, and use it later to write to a file?  Another alternative would be to always use `\immediate` so that the chronology of typesetting is respected.

Comment: This is, as far as I can tell, pretty much what Lev's answer does.  For some reason, when I tried simply putting in `\immediate`s in front of the `\write`s then it wasn't doing what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `filecontents` (CTAN).